# Xamarin Label IsVisible Propety isn't changing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, viewmodel

I have a PopUp Page and in this Popup page i have a Label with IsVisible Property bound to my ViewModel. However the site is not refreshing when the IsVisible Property is changing. Whats wrong with my code?

My Xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name der Einkaufsliste" />
        <Entry x:Name="entryList" FontSize="20"
               Placeholder="z.B. Lidl" />
        <Label Text="Liste schon Vorhanden!" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

My xaml.cs

```
PopupViewModel vm = new PopupViewModel();
    public PopupViewListeHinzufügen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPage master = new MasterPage();
        master.addList(entryList.Text);
    }

    public void ListeVorhandenMeldung()
    {
        vm.setLabelVisible();
    }
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class PopupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PopupViewModel()
    {
        IsVisible = false;
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void setLabelVisible()
    {
        IsVisible = true;
    }

    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When/where is the ListeVorhandenMeldung() method called? Are you sure it is called and is it on the main thread?

Comment: The method ListeVorhandenMeldung() is called in my databasecontroller when a list is saved

Comment: Try to change the property name "IsVisible" which you are binding with label.

Comment: does not change anything :/

Comment: The code you've shown looks correct, so there must be some other issue. Are you sure the database controller is calling ListeVorhandenMeldung() on the same instance of the viewmodel that's bound to the view? You could also try marshaling to the main thread with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to ensure you aren't trying to update the UI from a different thread.

Comment: May be the name itself is an issue 'IsVisible'. Try the property name something else. If still not resolved, try simply OnPropertyChanged();